# 「彼氏と彼女の　三三九度に　坊やおなかで　高砂や」?

Tags: translation, jokes

Saw this 都都逸 "彼氏と彼女の　三三九度に　坊やおなかで　高砂や" on the TV show 笑点:

http://www.ntv.co.jp/sho-ten/02_week/090329/week_01.html

My dictionary says 三三九度 = "perform the ceremony of the three-times-three exchange of nuptial cups", but I still do not understand the second half & hence the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

三三九度 is a ceremony performed at a wedding. 高砂や is a Japanese comic story related to a wedding. 坊やおなかで means "their child in her womb."

So the sentence means "Their child in her womb tells a Japanese comic story 高砂や at their wedding". That is about "shotgun wedding".

Comment: Thanks! I think the key here is knowing that 高砂や  is a rakugo story. I went off the rails by trying to look up  高砂 in dictionary.